# How to place the image, behind the Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm in the final stretch of the game and when I put the background image, it overlaps the Canvas, how do I fix this? - **Google translator**

[game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35N0q.png)

[game with background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fJJa.jpg)

Comment: Set a background on the canvas itself.

Comment: Please include your current code as a [MCVE]. We can't see what's wrong with only screenshots. There are too many possibilities to generate both your description and what is shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

make the image as css background-image of the elements that contains the canvas or make the image absolute with lesser z-index value than the canvas

Comment: I didn't know there was a Z axis in CSS  :O Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) property of canvas

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var background = new Image();
background.src = "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/is_google_plus_one_icons/256/google_plus_one_-plus-1_canvas.png";
background.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0, 200, 100);   
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(200,100);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Make use of `onload` property of image to draw the canvas contents.